# Django: Filter Items similar to given Item

Tags: python, django, sentence-similarity

I have a django Backend (Postgre DB).

Suppose a given table, say A, has charfield called 'message'. Now, what I want to do is find all items in A which have similar 'message' to the 'message' field of a given instance. The similarity will be based on some algorithm. TL;DR I want to find items based on item-item similarity.

The question has 3 parts:

1. How can I do it? Can I do it in real time (slow) or will I have to precompute similarity between all items in table A. (This might blow up my DB)
2. How can I find similarity between 'message' fields? Note that the item is more like a 400 char post than a group of keywords. I've come across many algorithms that that calculate string distance, but I don't think that will cut it. I think something TF-IDF followed by cosine similarity is more appropriate.
3. How do I achieve above in production setting? As in what data-structure should use to optimize request response time vs storage.

Comment: Just an idea. Tag the 'message' field with the prominent key words. Then search for tags.

Comment: That is a great idea. But the procedure is to be automated. Hence, I need a good way to extract keywords. The problem is 'message' might be non-standard English.

Comment: Umm... How aboout this, for a long message if I consider only verbs and nouns, it will be reasonably a small set of keywords. In case of non-standard English , there's no easy way out.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My dataset to a very large extent is non-standard English

Comment: What you need is called "full text search", postgres has support for it see here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/textsearch.html, there is a bunch of third party search engines for it too like sphinx http://sphinxsearch.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might do the trick:

http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v2.4.1/searchqueryset_api.html#more-like-this

```
SearchQuerySet.more_like_this(self, model_instance)
```

You can pass in an instance of the model, to fetch similar results.